# Testing not-empty Group captures

Tags: python, regex

Beginner python question.

I want to learn simple python syntax to test not-empty Group captures.

The example not important, what I want is learn to look at not-empty capture

I tried this

```
subj = 'abc123 bbb22 cc'
rgx = re.compile(r'[a-z]+(\d+)?')
for match in re.finditer(rgx,subj):
    print (match.group(1))
```

This give **both** the empty and not empty Group#1: 123, 22, **None**.

Okay. From here, can you teach me how:

- count the not-empty G1 capture
- print just the not-empty G1 capture

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the match is empty or not using `if match`:

```
subj = 'abc123 bbb22 cc'
rgx = re.compile(r'[a-z]+(\d+)?')
for match in re.finditer(rgx,subj):
    if match.group(1):
        print (match.group(1))
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
subj = 'abc123 bbb22 cc'
rgx = re.compile(r'[a-z]+(\d+)?')
result = [i for i in re.findall(rgx, subj) if i]
for match in result:
    print (match)
```

Comment: Thank you but this does the same as my code: if G1 is empty it prints None.

Comment: It still doesn't look right, or maybe I just can't read Python.

Comment: @KendallFrey, Please see my demo as I showed Hans a few comments up.

Comment: In 4 minute I can accept your answer thank you :) Before then two questions: to count, just a n+=1 in the for match, or a python trick? Also why is 2nd method better. Thank you so much for great python lesson

Comment: Better because you make list that can be use with list comprehension?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand it now. I'm not familiar with the Python regex engine.

Comment: @HansSchindler, For your second question, the second method is more compact and only creates a list of the non `None` values in the regex searches

Comment: @HansSchindler, You also don't need to do `.group(1)` in the second method

Comment: `You also don't need to do .group(1) in the second method` Yes that is incredible. What is happening there?

Comment: @HansSchindler, `findall` returns a list of strings by default and not a `re.match` object as in the other cases.

Comment: But how does it know only print G1?

Comment: Also for case when I don't want to look at the non-empty G1s, is there quick way to only count them?

Comment: @HansSchindler, `findall` creates a tuple of strings of all the captured groups in a string so no group(0). In the case of just one captured group, it doesn't do a tuple but rather just a string.

Comment: @HansSchindler, Count what? The number of non-empty matches?

Comment: @HansSchindler, I think the best way to explain `findall` would be with a demo. Please wait a few mintues, I'll put a demo here.

Comment: @HansSchindler, Here as you can see, there are more that 1 captured groups so `findall` creates a list of tuples. [__DEMO__](http://repl.it/S4K)

Comment: To count number of non-empty matches, just do: `len(result)`

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you. `Count what? The number of non-empty matches?` Yes. For when I just want to count number of not-empty G1. For option 2 I do `len(result)` For option 1, just n+=1 counter?

Comment: Ah you said `len(result)` when I was writing to you. Thank you for wonderful answer. Now I go read the doc for findall :)

Comment: @HansSchindler, Yes `n += 1` for the first option. The n += 1 will have to be _inside_ the if statement.