# Regex to negative match one pattern and positive match another pattern

Tags: regex

I want to search my C++ source code for places where the `++` operator is used, but not if part of a `for` statement.

For example I want to match all these lines

```
a[i++] = b;
i = ++i;
if (x++) y==0;
```

but I don't want to match

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
```

I have tried the regex, which uses negative lookback

```
(?<!foo).*\+\+
```

but this matches everything.  Here is my playground: https://regex101.com/r/MXLZ2m/1

If I was hacking at the command line, I would run my code through `grep \+\+ | grep -v foo` but I don't have the luxury of specifying on positive regex and one negative one in my IDE.

This question is basically a specific example of doing`grep re1 | grep -v re2` using just one regex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: What about `++i`, or `i ++` (with space), or `i+=1` or `while(i++<9)` or `for(x=f(i++);x;x=f(x))`, ...etc...etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\bfor ?\((?:[^;]*;){2}[^+]+\+\+\);|(\+\+)
```

and take only the matches that are captured.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VhqtnF/1)

The idea is to match, but not capture, what you don't want and match and capture (to capture group 1) what you do want. So skip matches for which capture group 1 is empty and extract the contents of capture group 1 for matches that capture.

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
\bfor\(   # match 'for(' preceded by a word boundary
(?:       # begin non-capture group
  [^;]*;  # match zero or more characters other than '*', then match '*'
){2}      # end non-capture group and execute it twice
[^+]+     # match one or more characters other than '+'
\+\+\)    # match '++)'
|         # or
(\+\+)    # match and capture '++'
```

Comment: This is a useful answer and the demo is appreciated, but it solves the problem of capturing, and I am interested in matching only. I only want to see the lines that have `++` but not `for`.

Comment: The idea, if it's not apparent, is that in code you run through the matches, discarding those where nothing has been captured, leaving only the matches of interest. I believe it's just one line of code but I'm not a Pythonite so I cannot include it in my answer. Perhaps another reader can do so. Incidentally, what to you plan to do with the `'++'` you are looking for? Replace them with another string?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: This will fail if there's a space after 'for' (which many editors add).

Comment: Mark, see the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555729/testing-not-empty-group-captures) for examples of code that loops through matches looking for captures.

Answer (score 0):

### Another version:

```
(?=^((?!\bfor\b).)*$).*\+{2}.*$
```

#### Explanations

Negative look-around inspired by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) :

```
^((?!\bfor\b).)*$
```

Look-around to get from start to end of line without putting "cursor" to the end of line.

It let the "cursor" at the start of the line but check there is no `for` in the line :

```
(?=^((?!\bfor\b).)*$)
```

Now we know that we are at start of line that doesn't contains any `for`. So we just need to get anything containing a `+` twice to the end of line :

```
.*\+{2}.*$
```

I hope it help.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a solution, which uses a negative lookahead instead of a lookbehind.

```
^(?!.*for).*\+\+
```

Comment: What about `"forty++";` and `"for(i=0;i<10;i++); cat++;`?